# How to set up a login session with Java and XML?

Tags: java, xml, session

I am working on a project and I have been using XML, Java and JSON to store information, process it and to transport it between my cloud service and my site.

The project is a web shop where it is important to keep the users logged in at all times during their shopping session.

At the moment, I just have a `Boolean` value in my JavaScript that is set to either `true` or `false` to emulate the log in principle, but this approach appears to me far not ideal.

I want to use sessions, but I have virtually no idea how this works and how would I go about doing this.

I am able to get the information from the cloud server and validate that the login information is correct and, consequently set my Boolean value to `true` but that is all at the moment.

What I am looking for is some information that might help me understand how do sessions work and which framework should I use.

I have tried googling around, but I have not found anything that seems to be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i got from your question is that you wanted to do the whole task of managing user data along with the login ,registration and all the proecss using xml,JSON thats preety good to do.
For that you need to chose java EE frame work .

If you are a begineer then its better you start from jsp servelts and read for session.well session in simple words are used to store the present state of something for eg if a user is logged in then you can maintain his data in session variable 
like

```
 HttpSession session =request.getSession(true);
 session.setAttribute("usrname",username);
```

Also you can set an object in this session object and get it used in any of your jsp page /servlet .
after the user logout you can remove that session variables and invalidate you session so that the information is no longer saved in that and user cannot get back to that page.session is maintained through an id which used everywhere .
[image]

also you can have look at this example for session
http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/ListenerSession.shtml

Comment: Thanks man! I don't get why I get negative votes though... Just 'cause I'm a scrub doesn't mean I don't ask good questions :P